# C++ How to debug a process spwaned by another

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to debug a faulty process which is spawned by another one. I've tried `__debugbreak(); __asm int 3;` image file execution but nothing seems to work. Does anyone has any ideas how to attach the debugger from the code?

Comment: Why do you need to attach the debugger from your code?
Can't you just do a regular attach to process?

Comment: The process is spawned from another process. The debugger is attached to the original one and I need to debug the spawned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one I sometimes use is

MessageBox(NULL, "Attach", "Attach", MB_OK)

You will need to link in the SDK and #include "windows.h" but that is about it.  A message box will pop up and wait until you click OK.  Just attach the debugger at that point, set you breakpoint and click OK.

This works as long as there isn't a time critical watchdog from the spawning process waiting for a reply from the spawned process.  If there is, you might need to increase the timeout so that you can start up VS and attach.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing else works I sometimes use a trick
in the beginning of the spawned process I put a

```
while(1)
{
    Sleep(1000); // +Breakpoint
}
```

attach to the process after it starts and use a "set next statement" to go pass the loop.

I usually use it to debug the OnStart() of windows services

Make sure to remove this code after the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio uses the DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS flag with CreateProcess. You can either switch to windbg, or attach the debugger in your code. E.g. get the active VisualStudio.DTE.11.0 object then call _DTE::Debugger to get the debugger, and call Debugger::LocalProcesses to get a list of processes. Find the desired process (e.g. by file name or creation time) then call Process::Attach.

Comment: Is there no way to just make Visual Studio debug a process and all the processes it spawns?

Comment: saw a lot of requests on Microsoft Connect, no action taken, must be hard to redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you didn't use [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of __debugbreak()?

Here's a [description of the differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea9yy3ey.aspx)

I've had cases where the it appeared the debugger didn't start, but there was actually a hidden dialog prompting me for what VS session/version to attach.  Make sure to alt-tab through windows to make sure this isn't happening to you.

Comment: According to that link, the only difference is that one requires system symbols to be available in order to get a usable call stack, while the other one doesn't. Aside from that, they're identical. Why, then, would you not use `__debugbreak()`?

Comment: Agreed - there should also be no reason why this doesn't work, but since it doesn't for the submitter, I'm wondering what happens with the other API call.  System symbols are generally worth having, and easy to install via VS/symsrv.